# Embedding database file in Shared project or Android asset doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-assets

### Shared Project approach

Trying to [embed database in Shared project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Embedding_in_Shared_Projects). Given in my Shared Project I put database.sqlite3 under Resources folder and ensure build action is Embedded resource:
[image: Build action]

However, it's not listed with [GetManifestResourceNames](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames/). Note that `DdgRepository` is a class within Shared Project and the code runs within that assembly where Embedded Resource must be present:

[image: Not listed]

And [GetManifestResourceStream](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream/p/System.String/) returns a null Stream.

### Project specific: Android Asset approach

Ohwell I still have an option to load database from Android Assets. So I put the database.sqlite3 file within Assets folder and ensure Build action is AndroidAsset:
[image: Build action]

However it is not listed as Asset and I cannot get then stream. Note that this code runs within Android specific project:
[image: Exception]

Using:

- Visual Studio 2017 15.4.0
- Xamarin 4.7.10.22
- Xamarin.Android SDK 8.0.0.33

What am I missing? I am nit asking how to do it. I'v read the docs. I don't understand why my assets and resources doesn't get embedded althought I follow the instructions.

Comment: @SushiHangover, I am not asking HOW to do it. I'v read the docs. I don't understand WHY my assets and resources doesn't get embedded although I follow the instructions.

Comment: You can not following the "instructions" as you are using the wrong code to open a stream, review the linked SO to see how a stream to an Android Asset is obtained so you can copy the DB to a R/W location.

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, it worked the Assets way with `ndroid.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open`. And I understand why it didn't work with `Android.Content.Res.Resources.System.Assets.Open`. I was looking under "System" resources, which provide access to only system resources rather than application res.


I'll just stracth my head a little bit why I can't see/use Embedded Resource in Shared project.